# Queues - Java - Clarification

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

I have been asked: Write the definitions of the method copyQueue and the copy constructor for the class QueueClass. 
Write a program to test these operations.

However, I don't understand method copyQueue and the copy constructor for the class QueueClass. I have read previous post on the subject matter and attempted to locate additional resources online. But I have been unsuccessful.

Could someone shed some light on the subject for me?

Comment: Is this a "homework" you got?

Comment: What is `QueueClass`? Do you know what a copy constructor is? Is this C++? One would assume that the `copyQueue` method is supposed to create and return a copy of the queue instance, but it's difficult to be sure without a specification. If you have trouble interpreting the assignment, I suggest you ask your instructor.